# How to run vue-cli build command when specified files modified?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js, vue-component

I can build my js file with this command

```
vue build main.js --dist dist --prod --lib
```

It is ok but I want to do it automaticaly when I change js or vue files. I don't want to use browserify, webpack, gulp, vuify etc.

I installed watch-run via npm and run this command.

```
watch-run -p '/Users/User/Data/root/vue/js/*.js' echo "hello"
```

It is working and saying hello when I change the js file. But when I change `echo "hello"` as `vue build /Users/User/Data/root/vue/js/main.js --dist dist --prod --lib` it does not work. There is nothing in terminal. No warning, no error nothing.

Do you have any idea how to do it for my minimal setup?

Comment: I'd say the issue is with the `--dist` / `--prod` / `--lib` flags. The `watch-run` package seems to recommend [wait-run](https://github.com/RickWong/wait-run) which appears to deal with the command syntax better

Comment: @Phil Super, wait-run is working very well. But the new issue is "wait-run" is closing the execution after the build finish.

Comment: This might help ~ http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we will add a `--watch` mode to it, stay tuned!

btw, why do you need this?

Comment: this is a good news. i need this because i dont like tools such as broserify, webpack and their config files. i want to start from scratch.

Comment: try `yarn gloal add vuejs/vue-cli`, `--watch` is there and doc has been updated.

Comment: Is it possible to watch .vue files also?

Comment: @kastelli it's using webpack's node.js api `compiler.watch`, everything you `require` will be watched.

Comment: Updated vue-cli and vue with npm but when i try to run `vue build --watch` it is saying  `error: unknown option --watch`

Comment: @kastelli npm i -g vuejs/vue-cli // btw, Yarn is much faster

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Did you now how to use stylus-loader with this way. I am getting `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stylus-loader'`

Comment: @kastelli did you run `npm i -D stylus stylus-loader` before using it?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with installing nodemon via npm.

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Then this command to monitor file changes and build the js.

```
nodemon -w /Users/User/Data/root/vue/assets/comp -w /Users/User/Data/root/vue/assets/js -x "cd /Users/User/Data/root/vue/assets/js/; vue build main.js --dist ../dist --prod --lib" -e vue,js
```

I hope this helps someone looking for a similar solution